# Solid angle relation between sinθ dϕdθ and d(cos(θ))dϕ

Tags: derivatives, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, solid-angle

I am a bit confused with regards to the concept of solid angle.

Why is the solid angle which is defined as $\sin \theta {\rm d}\phi\, {d\rm }\theta$ equal to $\sin\theta\,{\rm d}\theta {\rm d}\phi = {\rm d}\cos\theta{\rm d}\phi$

Answer (score 2):

The identity

$$
\sin\theta\,{\rm d}\theta {\rm d}\phi = {\rm d}\cos\theta{\rm d}{\phi}
$$

comes from the fact that

$$
{\rm d}\cos\theta = \frac{{\rm d}\cos\theta}{{\rm d}\theta}{\rm d}\theta = -\sin \theta {\rm d}\theta
$$

Comment: but that doesn't account for  the negative sign which is what bothered me about that !

Comment: @DavidAbraham Remember that the integral goes accompanied by the absolute value of the Jacobbian, so the minus sign disappears

Answer (score 1):

use the following trick
$$\frac {d(cos(θ))}{dt}=-\sin(\theta) \frac {d \theta}{dt}$$
multiply by $dt$
$$ {d(cos(θ))}=-\sin(\theta){d \theta}$$